# does javascript equality for 2.0 === 2 - hold true for all browsers

Tags: javascript, floating-point, equality, triple-equals

I want to write a function to trim additional decimal 0's from floating point numbers like 2.0,  5.00 but not 3.04.

so I wrote this:

```
const trimZeroFromDecimal = value =>
  parseInt(value) === value ? parseInt(value) : value;
```

but will this equality between 2.0 and 2 hold true in all javascript environments - or are there any quirks to it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: There aren't any "extra" zeroes. JavaScript numbers are all floating point numbers and `2`, `2.0`, `2.00`, `2.000`, etc are all the same value. `2.0 === 2` is literally the same as `2 === 2` you've just used more code to express it.

Comment: How are passing the data to `trimZeroFromDecimal`? Does that come from an input? `2.0` is just number literal and it is no different to 2.